# Filter objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript

So I have an array with 3 objects

```
categories:[
{
 id: '1',
 name: 'firstItem',
 description: 'firstDesc'
}
{
 id: '2',
 name: 'secondItem',
 description: 'secondDesc'
}
{
 id: '3',
 name: 'thirdItem',
 description: 'thirdDesc'
}
]
```

My question is, how can I filter this array to get the same array of 3 objects but without 'description' property?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object?rq=1 ?

Comment: You want to `map`, not `filter`. And give it a function which takes an object and returns the same object with only `id` and `name` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use array.map to achieve this:

```js
const array = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'firstItem',
    description: 'firstDesc'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'secondItem',
    description: 'secondDesc'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'thirdItem',
    description: 'thirdDesc'
  }
];

const array1 = array.map(item => {
  const {
    description,
    ...rest
  } = item;
  return rest;
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Bro this question is answered alot of times.

Comment: Thank you :) that works for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner to mutate the original array:

```js
let arr = [{id: '1',name: 'firstItem',description: 'firstDesc'},{id: '2',name: 'secondItem',description: 'secondDesc'},{id: '3',name: 'thirdItem',description: 'thirdDesc'}];

arr.forEach(e => delete e.description);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you :) that also works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
let categories = [
{
 id: '1',
 name: 'firstItem',
 description: 'firstDesc'
}
{
 id: '2',
 name: 'secondItem',
 description: 'secondDesc'
}
{
 id: '3',
 name: 'thirdItem',
 description: 'thirdDesc'
}
];

let newCategories = categories.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }))
```

Comment: This is answered already alot of times.

Comment: Thank you :) that also works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to "filter" per say, as in depending on a condition removing **elements** from an array.

You want to **map** over your array and then for each object (item) composing this array you want to remove the description property

You can easily achieve this by using the `.map` method available for Arrays

The .map method works as follows (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
// For each object, return a new one without the description property
const result = yourArray.map(obj => {
  const { name, description, id } = obj;
  return { name, id };
})
```

Comment: Thank you :) thats what I was looking for